# how do you say "how long does it take to learn fluent korean" in korean?

Tags: grammar

does anyone know how to say "how long does it take to learn fluent Korean" in Korean?

Comment: 얼마 걸려야 유창하게 한국말을 할 수 있을까요?

Answer (score 1):

한국어를 유창하게 구사하려면(or 사용하려면) 시간이 얼마나(or 어느 정도) 걸릴까요(or 필요할까요)?

Comment: It's both okay to put '시간이' in there or not, to add a bit.

Answer (score -1):

above answers have same meaning with your sentence but they're not exact translations.

유창한 한국어를 배우려면 얼마나 걸리나요?